# How "Symbolic Constants in C " are read by Conditional Loops in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to use the symbolic constant in the condition or test of a conditional loop. Here is what I tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TEST 0

void main() {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != TEST)
        putchar(c);
}
```

I want to exit the program when I enter `0` as input. But it keeps copying my input even if I enter a `0`.
Can you guys help me understand why this happens?

Comment: The ASCII code for the character '0' is 48 (0x30), which different from integer 0 (your TEST)

Comment: `#define TEST 0`-->`#define TEST '0'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the program to stop when you type `0`, you should compare the return value of `getchar()` to the character constant `'0'` instead of the number `0`. Note that you should also check for `EOF` to avoid an infinite loop at end of file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TEST '0'

int main() {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != TEST)
        putchar(c);
    return 0;
}
```

Note however that if the program reads from a terminal, because the input is buffered both by the standard stream and by the terminal, the `'0'` byte will be be made available to the program until you hit the enter key.

Also note that the program will store on the first `0` byte, neven if this byte is part of a number such as `1024` or a word `Hell0`.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Now I know what mistake I was doing.

Comment: Also, I want to know why you used "int" but not "void" before main(). Is there any particular reason?

Comment: @HarshitGupta: I used `int` because the Standard defined the `main` function return type as `int`. The return value of `main` is passed as an argument to the `exit()` system call that returns to the system, providing the exit status of the process. The C Standard makes a special case of the `main` function: if this function finished without a `return` statement, the value `0` is returned, but do not rely on this as some older compilers do not implement this special case. Defining `main` as `void main()` is incorrect.